# Database field type int or varchar

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, entity-relationship

When i have a table for example with Users and that table has a user type field, can i just make the user type field an int, and when programming i know that type=1 is admin, and type=2 others users, etc ? Or i should put type="admin", type="other" in varchar, and then in the app anyone can understand what type is, and what each value represents ?
Another solution is making a UserType table, just with "id" and "description" and connect it to the User, but is that good for performance ? Just to know what the id means ?

If i use Int, only who is developing know what 1 and 2 means. Which is the best practice and pros and cons of each one? Thank you

Table example:

```
User
_________
id
name
email
type
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have two tables `users` and `users_types`.

```
users                          users_types
-----                          -----------
id INT                         id INT
name VARCHAR(100)              title VARCHAR(20)
email VARCHAR(100)
type INT (References user_types(id))
```

This is how I always do it. For the following reasons:

- Easy to maintain and continue by someone else in my absence
- Keeps tables simple and light
- Enhances performance
- Easy to extend in case more groups needs to be added/dropped(scalability)
- Users can be added or removed from groups
- rights can be assigned in batches.

Comment: Usually i do this way. But why adding a reference table key would enhance performance ? In the application side it's more quick to do the query without the join, just with "where type=2"

Comment: You could also do where on two tables as well. You can stick to one table if your application would remain small and you would maintain it forever. Else, it would be better to separate groups from  users.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a small number of fairly static types, I have often used a 3-character mnemonic instead of an integer.  Using only capital letters, that offers 17,576 permutations, many of which are easily recognized.  For proof, consider that 50 states are known by a 2-character postal code, and all the world's airports by a 3-letter code.  I bet you know where LAX is.

If you don't use a separate table for the types, you can use a CHECK constraint or a user-defined type to effect the same enforcement.  If there's only one description column (say, "name"), you can include a computed column in a CASE statement.

But if you don't want to change the schema every time a new type shows up, a separate table with an FK constraint will serve you well.  You can use a view to incorporate the descriptive information, although for many purposes the mnemonic will serve just as well or better.